# ADO.Net Entity Data Model wizard is getting closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a hard time with this error. The wizard of `ADO.Net` Entity Data Model just closes at the mid of the process.

I'm using `VS 2013` Update 4, `Entity Framework 6.1.3` and `.NET Framework 4.5`. It is a ASP.NET MVC 5 project. And I'm working on`Windows Server 2012 R2` with EF Tools installed.

I have tried several version of `EF`, including `6.0.0`, `6.1.0`, even `5.0.0` on a `ASP.Net MVC 4` project and nothing.

On this MVC 4 project using `EF 5.0.0`, I was able to proceed on the wizard, but it gave me this error when I chose the DB and proceeded:

```
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntityContainerMapping' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I also repaired VS but nothing changed.

Comment: Ya this is an issue with power tools it doesn't show complete error but there might be error connecting to your db or model error. Do you have source somewhere?

Comment: the connection to the db its fine because i tested the connection. what do you mean by source @lazy ? the db is not local

Comment: What version of EF tools? There was a similar bug in initial version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873639/entityframework-cant-generate-db-first-edmx-null-reference-cannot-load-type

Comment: Oh okay. The wizard is to get EDMX from the db. When you say wizard works with EF uninstalled / then do you get EDMX?

Comment: i have the EF Tools 6.1.1 version. I tried with 6.1.3 and nothing too @SteveGreene

Comment: @lazy i only get the EDMX if i create an empty model. Then on the EDMX model created, i right-click on it and i do Update Model from Database, which opens the wizard. Then i setup my db connection, click Next and the wizard closes

Comment: @lazy, answering your question about EF uninstalled, i am able to proceed the db connection setup, next i have to choose the EF version which there are two: EF 6.X and EF 5.0. None of them works, the wizard closes..

Comment: Are you able to reverse engineer for code first using the power tools without generating the EDMX? As indicated by other places and links it seems version or upgrade issue but unable to replicate it on my end.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @MikeG My solution was using MVC3 instead of MVC4 and it worked.

Comment: To resolve this issue I have made these step and it solved [Entity Data Model wizard disappears Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178496/entity-data-model-wizard-disappears-sql-anywhere-17/42554921#42554921)

Comment: Credit to @akunamatata: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178496/entity-data-model-wizard-disappears-sql-anywhere-17/42554921#42554921 This solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to remove existing data connections.
Go to View and select Server Explorer in your Visual Studio edition.
Look for data connections that might be marked as bad, right click and delete the connection.
The Data Model Wizard should now be functioning correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's now fixed since it pasted a long time, but I remember that did not worked